# Convert array to string while grouping by pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, string-formatting

I have an array of latitudes and longitudes in javascript, like this:

```
a = [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3, ...] // assert(a.length % 2 = 0)
```

and I would like to create a string like this:

```
s = "lat1,lon1 lat2,lon2 lat3,lon3 ..."
```

that is, each latlon pair has a comma separating the pair, and the pairs are separated by a space.

I'm a bit stuck here (mostly because I know very little of javascript):

```
    function polylineToKml(p)     
    {
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i+=2)
        {
            var lat = p[i];
            var lon = p[i+1]
            // now what?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
var s = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i+=2)
{
    s.push(a[i] + "," + a[i+1]);
}

s = s.join(" ");
```

Comment: Cannot get much simpler than that! I used this!

Answer (score 2):

In a more functional way:

```
function polylineToKml(p) {
  return p.map(function(el, i) {
    return el + (i % 2 > 0 ? " " : ",");
  }).join("").trim();
}
```

And if your environment supports ES6:

```
var polylineToKml = p =>
  p.map((el, i) => el + (i % 2 > 0 ? " " : ",")).join("").trim();
```

Comment: Should really remove the extra whitespace that will be on the end of the result

Comment: I'll favor the other answer for legibility (specially for those like me not much into these idioms), but it's good to know these lambda tricks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function polylineToKml(p) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0, l = p.length; i < l; i += 2) {
        var lat = p[i];
        var lon = p[i + 1];
        s += lat + ',' + lon;

        // don't add a space at the end
        if (i !== l - 2) s += ' ';
    }
    return s;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7yn21r2k/)

Answer (score 0):

one more way...

```
function polylineToKml(p){
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length - 1; i++){
        s += p[i] + ",";
    }
    s += p[p.length - 1];
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should adopt a proper way to organize your data set, one way is to use JSON array with key-value pairs, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var a = [1.234, 2.345, 3.456, 5.456, 4.653, 2.567]
var coordinates = [];
for (var i=0; i < a.length; i=i+2){
    coordinates[i/2] = {"latitude":a[i], "longitude":a[i+1]}
}

for (var i=0; i < coordinates.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=
    coordinates[i].latitude + ", " + coordinates[i].longitude + "<br>";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this way, the coordinates will be represented as such:

```
coordinates = [
    {"latitude":"1.234", "longitude":"2.345"}, 
    {"latitude":"3.456", "longitude":"5.456"},
    {"latitude":"4.653", "longitude":"2.567"}
];
```

Find out more on http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp